# Where should RBAC be implemented?

Tags: authorization, scalability, rbac

To give you some background, I have frequently worked with RBAC implemented on the SQL level, but I read in some articles that it might not be very scalable.

Should RBAC be implemented on, say:

- On the Database level (i.e. row or column based access control)
- On the Application level (i.e. logic in the code) perhaps with some document storage support
- On some other level

What are the pros and cons of each approach in terms of scalability and what is the gold industry standard?

Comment: I don't think there is a gold standard, it would depend on your application, but generally speaking RBAC becomes a problem when your app has too many roles, because you'd have to fetch the user's roles prior to doing anything, which would impact performance (if you care about that)

Answer (score 0):

As  per my experience RBAC in case of B2B and B2C apps,
Application level is widely implemented and accepted.

on same note

if you like  you could  give below a shot
[image]
[image]

The above RBAC is part of current ongoing boilerplate platform below

[Nodejs_Postgresql_VanillaJS_Fastify](https://github.com/matt212/Nodejs_Postgresql_VanillaJS_Fastify)